# How to use v-model within Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

1. Below is my app.js file. When using v-model, and NOT v-modal, do I need to import anything in the app.js file or download anything via npm? I have already ran npm install. The template is working fine and all normal vue functionality is working, I am only stuck when it comes to v-model. v-model is not working. The email is not appearing in the body when I use v-model.

```js
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('formtemp', require('./components/formtemp.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

2. Vue Component

```html
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input
                v-model='email'
                type="text"
                id="email"
                placeholder="email"
                class="form-control"
        >
        <h1>Email: {{email}}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                email: ''
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"? What doesn't work?

Comment: Did you read the title or the description body?

Comment: @DerDeutsche I'm as confused as Travis. Your question is unclear. Are you not seeing the `email` output in your `h1` when you type in the input?

Comment: @TravisBritz and ceejayoz I have appended this to the description body, I apologies for any confusion "The email is not appearing in the body when I use v-model."

Comment: `v-model` is default vue functionality so it should just work when you have Vue. Id suggest using `"` as well vs `'`, it might be the bug already

Comment: I've just copied the code from your vue component into my own example component and it worked perfectly, so I think you can rule out the code inside the component as the problem.

Comment: This could be one of a few things. Please don't take these questions the wrong way but it's just good to know that nothing has been missed. 1) Have you run `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` since making any changes to your component? 2) Are there any errors/issues in either the browser console or during compilation in the terminal/cli? Are you able to show how you're including the `formtemp` in your html (assuming that is the component in your example)?

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing **formtemp** component generates a form element.

I think **formtemp** is not including the **Example component** and as such the input elements it’s generating are outside the form element and not sent when making the HTTP call.

Including the **Example component** inside your form component should fix it.